# Doubt in using $dx\wedge dy$

Tags: exterior-algebra

In my class notes there was this question to show that $d^2f=dy\wedge dx(f_{yx}-f_{xy})$, i did mannaged to find the correlation as follows
$$d^2f=d(dxf_x+dyf_y)=dx\wedge df_x+dy\wedge df_y$$
$$=dx\wedge (dxf_{xx}+dyf_{xy})+dy\wedge (dxf_{yx}+dyf_{yy})=dx\wedge dyf_{xy}+dy\wedge dxf_{yx}$$
and because $dx\wedge dy=-dy\wedge dx$ I can find $dy\wedge dx(f_{yx}-f_{xy})$.
My doubt is more of a curiosity, can i day that$$dx\wedge dy(...)=(...)dx\wedge dy$$
or is there a convention against it?

Comment: You can, since differentiable (or smooth) functions can be viewed as $0$ forms. That being said, just because you can do something doesn't mean it is advisable. Why not just write it as $d(f_xdx+f_ydy)$